# Twilio Studio Engagement Not Completing

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

I am having difficulty understanding why my Twilio Studio engagement gets "stuck" after my function's callback.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    twiml.say("Hello sir");
    console.log(twiml.toString());
    callback(null,twiml);
    };
```

[picture of Studio flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYpj9.png)

My Studio flow will execute up to function_2, return a 200 status but it will never move on to either say_play_2 or say_play_3. I have to go into the Flow Logs and manually Stop Engagement.

Am I missing something in the callback to indicate there is no more code to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here - albeit a new one!

The issue is that your callback function hangs up and `say_play_2` is left hanging - which means the engagement doesn't complete.

I intentionally broke the code in the Twilio Function and `say_play_3` then said "Failure" and the engagement completed, proving that that part of your Flow was correct.

If you swap `say_play_2` for a `Send Message widget`, for example, the engagement will complete as it can send a message on successfully completing the function.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Layla - thank you so much! That was definitely the piece I was missing.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!